# Does anyone have experience with programming an Fpod to turn on when upside-down-vertical?

Tags: equipment

The Fpod works well when programmed to turn on at any angle.
But when it was programmed with the default settings, it:

1. Was detecting test taps while in the horizontal mode, when it should have been off.
2. Worked briefly for 45 sec and then did not detect sounds 2.5 min after it was turned upside down (i.e., when it should have been recording).

Any suggestions on what to try here would be much appreciated.

Thanks

C